# Using JSON with an object

Tags: arrays, json, object, stringify

I have an object like

```
data: Array[1];
```

which can be accessed like

```
data[0].name
data[0].place
```

I am trying to convert this to JSON using like

```
var arr = JSON.stringify(data);
```

which returns

```
var arr = [{"name": "blah", "place": "ca"}]
```

But Im confused how to use this arr now its stringified ? How do I access for example the "name" value ? I tried `arr.name` but that doesn't seem to work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array is

```
arr == [{"name": "blah", "place": "ca"}];
```

That object is the first item in the array

```
arr[0] == {"name": "blah", "place": "ca"}
```

and its properties...

```
arr[0].name == "blah"
```

Answer (score 0):

your "name" is inside the hash/associative array which is inside an array

so u need to grab hash/associative array first, using

```
arr[0]
```

and then u can access your attributes.